# Fujitsu Eternus dx80 storage - Intake temp error

Tags: storage

I've managed to configure Fujitsu Eternus dx80 storage (network/RAID group/volume) and from the moment I powered it I get an error message and a warning.

From Event log:

DB010000    DE Intake temperature sensor DE#00 Fault
06A31000    Controller Module#0(iSCSI 1.2GHz) BE Expander Warning

Looking into storage status it says: Intake temp error code 0x0002.

I found info on error in Eternus DX60 S2 Disk Storage System - User's Guide - Operation and it says:

*CE intake temperature error or DE intake
temperature error (sensor failure) is detected.
SS: Component subtype
dd: DE-ID ("00" for a controller enclosure)*

These messages are notified when "Module was broken" is enabled for Error Severity Level in the event notification setting. They are not notified during maintenance operations.

The other one:

*Controller Module#m(zz xxHz) BE Expander
Warning 
CM BE Expander error is detected.
SS: Component subtype
MM: CM module ID (10 – 11)
m: CM number (0 – 1)
zz: Model name (FC4G, SAS, or iSCSI)
xx: CPU frequency (1.2GHz)
pp...: Component number
ss...: Serial number
rr...: Version*

What is there to do?

Comment: Contact Fujitsu support.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a hardware fault. Have your vendor replace the hardware.